# Why do my values not change after running my function?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove outliers from columns. Lets say I have:

```
rand_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})
```

If I do:

```
rand_df = rand_df[rand_df['A'] > 2]
```

I get a new df which is what I want. However if I try:

```
def some_fxn(df, col):
    df = df[df[col] > 2]

some_fxn(rand_df, 'A')
```

My df is unaltered. What do I need to do to enable this function to operate properly?

Answer (score 2):

Try not to assign in a function call, instead return and assign it:

```
def some_fxn(df, col):
    return df[df[col] > 2]

df = some_fxn(rand_df, 'A') # assign to df for updating or any other variable for copy
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `return` at the end of your function. A function without an explicit return statement returns None.

```
def some_fxn(df, col):
    return df[df[col] > 2]

some_fxn(rand_df, 'A')

Out[412]: 
   A  B
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting pass by reference behavior. Python neither has pass by reference nor pass by value. It just has [bindings to names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

The following code shows when the ID of the object changes

```
import pandas as pd
rand_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})
rand_df = rand_df[rand_df['A'] > 2]
print(rand_df)


def some_fxn(df, col):
    print(id(df))
    df = df[df[col] > 2]
    print(id(df))
    
rand_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})
some_fxn(rand_df, 'A')
print(rand_df)
```

So you have no choice but return the new value.